# unappend circle when dragged out of group

Tags: jointjs

How to unappend a circle element when I drag it out of group? Currently I am able to append it to the group but not able to unappend it on drag. If any body have an idea please help. I am new to d3js and javascript

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/q7L9qdyv/

Code:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", 800)
                        .attr("height", 803);

                //Draw the Circle  
                var circle = svg.append("circle")
                        .attr("r", 25)
                        .attr("cx", 35)
                        .attr("cy", 145)
                        .style("stroke-opacity", .9)
                        .style("stroke", "green")
                        .style("fill", "white")
                        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
                        .classed("baseCircle", true); // created a class to identify

                var targetCircle = circle;
                var tempCircle = circle;

                //unique id for circles
                function guid() 
                {
                    function _p8(s) 
                    {
                        var p = (Math.random().toString(16) + "000000000").substr(2, 8);
                        return s ? "-" + p.substr(0, 4) + "-" + p.substr(4, 4) : p;
                    }
                    return _p8() + _p8(true) + _p8(true) + _p8();
                }

                //function to move circles
                function moveCircle() 
                {
                    d3.select(this)
                            .attr('cx', d3.event.x)
                            .attr('cy', d3.event.y);
                }

                //Move the group along wth elements/Drag Behaviour for Group
                var dragGroup = d3.behavior.drag()
                        .origin(function () {
                            var g = this;
                            return {x: d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate[0],
                                y: d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate[1]};
                        })
                        .on("drag", function (d, i) {
                            g = this;
                            translate = d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate;
                            console.log(translate);
                            x = d3.event.dx + translate[0],
                                    y = d3.event.dy + translate[1];
                            d3.select(g).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
                            d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
                        });

                //Group element
                var targetG = svg.append("g")
                        .call(dragGroup)
                        .style('cursor', 'move')
                        .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)");

                //Append rectangle to group
                targetG.append("rect")
                        .attr("fill", "none")
                        .style("stroke", "black")
                        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
                        .attr("width", 200)
                        .attr("height", 200)
                        .style("fill", "white");

                //Drag behaviour starts for circles
                var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
                        .on("dragstart", dragstart)
                        .on("drag", drag)
                        .on("dragend", dragend);

                //Start
                function dragstart() {
                    console.log("circle dragged is::" + d3.select(this).attr("id"));

                    if (d3.select(this).classed("baseCircle") === true) {

                        targetCircle = svg.append("circle")
                                .attr("r", 25)  //get radius from targetCircle and also styles?
                                .attr("cx", targetCircle.attr("cx"))
                                .attr("cy", targetCircle.attr("cy"))
                                .style("fill", "white")
                                .style("stroke", "green")
                                .style("stroke-width", "2px");
                        targetCircle.call(drag);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        targetCircle = d3.select(this);
                        tempCircle = this;
                    }
                    targetCircle.classed("dragTarget", true).attr("id", "dragTargetId");
                }

                //Drag
                function drag()
                {
                    targetCircle.attr("cx", d3.event.x)
                            .attr("cy", d3.event.y);
                }

                //End
                function dragend(d) {
                    //Get event x and y
                    var tx = targetCircle.attr("cx"),
                            ty = targetCircle.attr("cy");

                    var flag = 0;
                    //Select all elements in svg
                    try {
                        var elemArr = svg.selectAll("*").each(function (d, i) {
                            //If the element is a member of a group, check
                            if ($(this.parentNode).is("g")) {
                                //Get coordinates
                                var box = this.getBBox();
                                var bx = box.x,
                                        by = box.y,
                                        bw = box.width,
                                        bh = box.height;
                                //Make shape inherit translate of parent element
                                var translate = d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("transform");
                                var translate = translate.substring(translate.indexOf("translate(") + 10, translate.length);
                                translate = (translate.substring(0, translate.indexOf(")"))).split(",");

                                bx += parseInt(translate[0]);
                                by += parseInt(translate[1]);
                                //Check if within x and y bounds
                                if (tx >= bx && tx <= (bx + bw) && !flag && ty >= by && ty <= (by + bh))
                                {
                                    //Flag to prevent further action
                                    flag = 1;
                                    //Append target circle to g element
                                    targetG.append("circle")
                                            .attr("r", 25)  //get radius from targetCircle and also styles?
                                            .attr("id", guid())
                                            .classed("circleAddedClass", true)
                                            .attr("cx", d3.mouse(this)[0])
                                            .attr("cy", d3.mouse(this)[1])
                                            .style("fill", "white")
                                            .style("stroke", "black")
                                            .style("stroke-width", "2px")
                                            .call(
                                                    d3.behavior.drag()
                                                    .on("dragstart", function () {
                                                        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
                                                    })
                                                    .on('drag', moveCircle).origin(function () {
                                                var t = d3.select(this);
                                                return {x: t.attr("cx"), y: t.attr("cy")};
                                            }));

                                    targetCircle.remove();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (e) {
                        log(e);
                    }
                }
                function log(s) {
                    console.log(s);
                    return s;
                }
                circle.call(drag);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.baseCircle {
    stroke-opacity: 0.9;
    stroke: green;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    fill: white;
}
.dragTarget {
    stroke: green;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    fill: white;
}
.circleAddedClass {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    fill: white;
}
```

---

**Script**

I reorganized your code a bit

```
// unique id for circles
function guid() {
    function _p8(s) {
        var p = (Math.random().toString(16) + "000000000").substr(2, 8);
        return s ? "-" + p.substr(0, 4) + "-" + p.substr(4, 4) : p;
    }
    return _p8() + _p8(true) + _p8(true) + _p8();
}

function getNode(d3Element) {
    return d3Element[0][0];
}

// check if within bounds
function isWithin(x, y, box) {
    return (x >= box.x && x <= (box.x + box.width) && y >= box.y && y <= (box.y + box.height))
}

function getTranslate(t) {
    var translate = d3.transform(t.getAttribute("transform")).translate;
    return {
        x: Number(translate[0]),
        y: Number(translate[1])
    };
}


var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 800)
            .attr("height", 803);


// movement for a transformed element
var dragG = d3.behavior.drag()
                // set the origin to the start position
                .origin(function () {
                    return getTranslate(this);
                })
                .on("drag", function () {
                    d3.select(this).attr(
                        "transform",
                        "translate(" +
                            d3.event.x + "," +
                            d3.event.y + ")");
                });

// drop group
var targetG = svg.append("g")
                .style('cursor', 'move')
                .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)")
                .call(dragG)

// append rectangle to group
targetG.append("rect")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
        .attr("width", 200)
        .attr("height", 200)
        .style("fill", "white");


// drag functions
var draggedCircle;
var circleDrag = function () {
    draggedCircle
        .attr("cx", d3.event.x)
        .attr("cy", d3.event.y);
}

function circleDragEnd() {
    // get event x and y
    var dx = Number(draggedCircle.attr("cx"));
    var dy = Number(draggedCircle.attr("cy"));
    if (draggedCircle.classed("circleAddedClass")) {
        var t = getTranslate(getNode(draggedCircle).parentNode);
        console.log([dx, dy])
        dx += t.x;
        dy += t.y;
        console.log([dx, dy])
    }

    svg.selectAll("g").each(function () {
        var rect = d3.select(this).select("rect");
        if (rect.length === 1) {
            var box = getNode(rect).getBBox();

            // the actual coordinates of the element must include the parent's transform too
            var t = getTranslate(this);
            box = {
                x: box.x + t.x,
                y: box.y + t.y,
                width: box.width,
                height: box.height
            }

            if (isWithin(dx, dy, box)) {
                if (!draggedCircle.classed("circleAddedClass")) {
                    draggedCircle = draggedCircle.remove()
                                        .attr("cx", dx - t.x)
                                        .attr("cy", dy - t.y)
                                        .attr("id", guid())
                                        .classed("dragTarget", false)
                                        .classed("circleAddedClass", true);

                    // append target circle to g element
                    this.appendChild(getNode(draggedCircle))
                }
            } else if (draggedCircle.classed("circleAddedClass")) {
                if (getNode(draggedCircle).parentNode === this) {
                    draggedCircle = draggedCircle.remove()
                                        .attr("cx", dx)
                                        .attr("cy", dy)
                                        .classed("dragTarget", true)
                                        .classed("circleAddedClass", false);

                    getNode(svg).appendChild(getNode(draggedCircle))
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

// drag behaviour for circle instances
var dragCircleInstance = d3.behavior.drag()
                            .on("dragstart", function () {
                                draggedCircle = d3.select(this)
                                d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
                            })
                            .on("drag", circleDrag)
                            .on("dragend", circleDragEnd);

// drag behaviour for circle template
var dragCircleTemplate = d3.behavior.drag()
                            .on("dragstart", function () {
                                draggedCircle = svg.append("circle")
                                                .attr("r", 25)  //get radius from targetCircle and also styles?
                                                .attr("cx", d3.select(this).attr("cx"))
                                                .attr("cy", d3.select(this).attr("cy"))
                                                .classed("dragTarget", true)
                                                .call(dragCircleInstance);
                            })
                            .on("drag", circleDrag)
                            .on("dragend", circleDragEnd);

// draw the circle template
var circle = svg.append("circle")
                .attr("r", 25)
                .attr("cx", 35)
                .attr("cy", 145)
                .classed("baseCircle", true)
                .call(dragCircleTemplate);
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/f7u11xm4/

Comment: Thanks again @potatopeelings. Though it looks a bit advanced for me, its working. Next I would like to connect the circles with line connections as in the example: https://gist.github.com/lgersman/5370827. Any start up ideas for me in implementing it?

Comment: Checkout https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js - it's pretty simple to draw a line through points that you want (scroll to the very end). by the way, you might want to check out http://fabricjs.com/ - most of the functionality you are looking for should already be in it and if you are lucky you might even find exactly what you are trying to build. Cheers!

Comment: Just a quick question..Can I mix fabricjs with d3 js? or I have to implement the complete functionality in fabricjs itself?

Comment: you can't mix - fabric.js is canvas. The d3 you are doing is svg.

Comment: Oh :/ I have to use only svg - requirement from my boss at work

Comment: I can see the line drawing through points in dashingd3 but my requirement is to drag to draw a line and attach to circles as a connection. I don't know where to start from?

Comment: Darn. That said, you might want to check if there's already a solution that's out there on the interwebs. What you are trying to build seems fairly complex but not so niche - it might be easier to adapt than to build from scratch.

Comment: I know its complex. I have checked out raphaeljs, paperjs, snap svg, jsplumb etc. All of them lacks one or other functionality I require. After weeks of research, only d3js has most of the functionality I require though its complexity threw me off.

Comment: check out http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/ and also force directed layouts in d3. I haven't actually used either of these to be honest. You might want to ask a question (I think http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com would be your best bet) about which d3 plugin would be best maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the links. Looks like cola js is compatible with d3 js :) Hope I find a solution soon!

Comment: @potoatopeelings When creating a new circle on clone, I want to create a circle inside a group like this`var dragCircleTemplate = d3.behavior.drag()
                        .on("dragstart", function () {
                            draggedCircle = svg.append("g").append("circle")` but I am getting error: `Cannot read property 'getBBox' of null`

Comment: could you please help me with this: http://jsfiddle.net/980tyzqL/1/  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836925/appending-text-to-shape

Answer (score 1):

If I was to code review this I'd make the following suggestion:

- Too many different drag handlers.  You need two: how do I drag the group and how do I drag a circle.
- Treat this as a state machine and ask what are the various states of my circle -  not in box and dragged in, in box and dragged out, in box and dragged in, out of box and dragged out.  Code to these possibilities.
- I found how you do your `dragstart` confusing and prone to problems.  I would just create a static circle that marks where you drag from and clone on drag end.  This of course adds another state; initial drag to anywhere.

All this in mind, here's my re-code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
    
    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", 800)
      .attr("height", 803);
                        
    //Move the group along wth elements/Drag Behaviour for Group
    var dragGroup = d3.behavior.drag()
      .origin(function () {
          var g = this;
          return {
            x: d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate[0],
            y: d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate[1]
          };
      })
      .on("drag", function (d, i) {
          g = this;
          translate = d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate;
          var x = d3.event.dx + translate[0],
              y = d3.event.dy + translate[1];
          d3.select(g).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
          d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
      });
      
      // circle drag
      function dragging(){
        var self = d3.select(this);
        self.attr("cx", d3.event.x)
          .attr("cy", d3.event.y);
      }
      
      // start
      function dragstart() {
        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
      }

      //End
      function dragend(d) {
        var self = d3.select(this);
        
        // is this the first time I'm dragged?
        // replace me with a new one
        if (self.classed('initialDragCircle')){
          // append a new inital draggable
          createInitialDragCircle();
          self.attr('class','dragCircle');
        }
        
        // get necessary coordinates
        var tx = self.attr('cx'),
            ty = self.attr('cy');
        
        var transG = d3.transform(targG.attr('transform')).translate;
        var bx = transG[0];
            by = transG[1];

        // was it outside of the box?
        if (self.classed('dragCircle')){
          var coords = d3.mouse(targG.node());
          var box = targRect.node().getBBox();
          // and now is it in box?
          if (coords[0] > 0 && coords[1] > 0 &&
              coords[0] < box.width && coords[1] < box.height) {
            
            targG.append("circle")
              .attr("r", 25)
              .attr("cx", coords[0])
              .attr("cy", coords[1])
              .style("stroke-opacity", .9)
              .style("stroke", "black")
              .style("fill", "white")
              .style("stroke-width", "2px")
              .attr('class','inBoxDragCircle')
              .call(drag);
            self.remove();
          }
        } 
        // was it in the box?
        else if (self.classed('inBoxDragCircle'))
        {
          var coords = d3.mouse(targG.node());
          var box = targRect.node().getBBox();
          // and now it is out of the box?
          if (coords[0] < 0 || coords[1] < 0 ||
              coords[0] > box.width || coords[1] > box.height) {
            coords = d3.mouse(svg.node());
            svg.append("circle")
              .attr("r", 25)
              .attr("cx", coords[0])
              .attr("cy", coords[1])
              .style("stroke-opacity", .9)
              .style("stroke", "green")
              .style("fill", "white")
              .style("stroke-width", "2px")
              .attr('class','dragCircle')
              .call(drag);
            self.remove();  
                
          }
        }
      }
      
    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
      .on("dragstart", dragstart)
      .on("drag", dragging)
      .on("dragend", dragend);
      
    //Group element
    var targG = svg.append("g")
      .call(dragGroup)
      .style('cursor', 'move')
      .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)");
      
    var targRect = targG.append("rect")
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "2px")
      .attr("width", 200)
      .attr("height", 200)
      .style("fill", "white");

    //Draw the Circle  
    svg.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 25)
      .attr("cx", 35)
      .attr("cy", 145)
      .style("stroke-opacity", .9)
      .style("stroke", "green")
      .style("fill", "white")
      .style("stroke-width", "2px")
      .classed("baseCircle", true);
    
    function createInitialDragCircle(){
      svg.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 25)
        .attr("cx", 35)
        .attr("cy", 145)
        .style("stroke-opacity", .9)
        .style("stroke", "green")
        .style("fill", "white")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
        .classed("initialDragCircle", true)
        .call(drag);
    };
    
    createInitialDragCircle();

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I like the idea of state machine. I have more elements like rectangle and path strings(polygon) and line connectors. How do I do drag behaviour for them. Do I have re-invent different drag behaviour for each of them? or use the existing drag behaviour? but rectangle and paths doesn't have cx and cy which kept me thinking..

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode as follows:-

1. Add `id=xxx` to all circle created.
2. a function to determine if circle is **inside** or **outside** container (the top_left and bottom_right points of container are used)
3. `d3.select("_dragged_circle_ID_").append("_another_<g>_container_");`